# Why is assigning 0 to a pointer a solution to a dangling pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dangling-pointer

What does the OS/Debugger do when a pointer is assigned 0?

Comment: Hmmm, nothing? it assigns 0 to the pointer. That's all. It's just used as a convention to know that the pointer is "unused" and not pointing to anything.

Comment: What specifically do you mean? Can you provide some source code of what you're trying to understand?

Comment: Your question's title and your question's body ask different things...

Comment: It does the hokey pokey and spins itself around

Comment: @haylem: strictly interpreting the standard, assigning zero doesn't actually require any paritcular state in the pointer, except to make it "be" a null pointer.  a null pointer should be convertable back to 0, but it could have any possible storage structure.  On systems where it's not possible to make an address read from the 0 address be an error, it could have some other value (hypothetically 0x8c000000 which won't be in ram or rom)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I know, see my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential problem this solves is that not all CPU's implement the same sorts of memory dereference semantics.  In some cases, it's not possible to make dereferencing an address after it has been `free()` into anything that looks like an error.  This is especially true on embedded processors.  In other cases, allocators may be very lazy about returning freed memory to the host operating system, for performance reasons.

Fundamentally, dereferencing such a pointer could lead to actually seeing the freed region, seeing a zeroed out region, seeing memory that has been returned by a subsequent allocation, or causing a cpu exception.  Since such an eventuality is completely reasonable, c++ has assigned this condition as "undefined behavior".

To get out of that situation, you want to have a way of distinguishing pointer values which have been freed or allocated.  As such, C++ requires that dereferencing a pointer that has been assigned `0` is an error, and converting such a pointer to an integer also return zero.

---

re: your current edit.

pointers don't exist for the purposes of operating systems.  At the lowest level, there are no strings, integers, floats or pointers of any sort.  only bytes.  When you write a c++ program that assigns 0 to a pointer value, the operating system simply doesn't enter into the equation.  that's totally up to the compiler implementation.

On the other hand, when you *dereference* such a pointer in your program, c++ requires that this is be a runtime error.  On embedded systems, that's basically not practical, 0 is a perfectly valid memory address on such systems, usually the SRAM is near that address.  If the compiler strictly implements the standard, it might insert a check before *every* dereference to see if it was null, and put the MCU in an error state, but that's unusual, since it would slow an already slow system and increase program size.

On more fully featured systems, those that have a memory management unit, the zero address in the application is usually not mapped to any physical page, so the operating system does help you here, by raising a segfault in the page program when it tries to access the null pointer value.

Comment: My understanding is that C++ actually does not define a null pointer as pointing to the memory location at address 0, just that converting them to int will give the result of 0. The simplest way to implement this just happens to be making the address 0 unusable.

Comment: indeed;  I was careful to say only that much.

Comment: `On the other hand, when you dereference such a pointer in your program, c++ requires that this is be a runtime error.` No, it doesn't. It's undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: Just as a point of interest are there are current implementations in use that anyone knows of where a null pointer isn't just implemented by setting the address to "zero"?

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to 0 is called a null pointer, and is usually used to indicate that it is not pointing to anything.  This can be checked for by the debugger/runtime/compiler/whatever to be sure you don't have a pointer to invalid data.  It's just an explicit recognition that the pointer isn't supposed to be pointing to anything just now.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning 0 (or NULL, or whatever is pre-defined for you depending on your imports) to a pointer is a **general convention** used to indicate that:

- **the pointer is unused** (not pointing to a memory address of interest),
- and that **it should NOT be dereferenced**.

Comment: This being a [c++] question, its not quite that... actually a pointer that has previously been assigned `0` puts it in a special state called "null pointer", which is a feature of the language.  generally what's special about a null pointer is that dereferencing it is a "runtime error", which is quite different from any other pointer value that has not been returned by `new` (or has been `delete`ed), which when dereferenced is "undefined behavior", which of course could mean anything (your hard drive is erased; your girlfriend gets pregnant, et.cetera)  this is not a mere matter of convention.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: indeed, I stand corrected and did not detail enough (+1-ed you already)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. I've had programs that ran as expected even though I dereferenced a null pointer before. Saying it is a runtime error would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's more useful to the programer than to the OS/debugger.

OS/debugger doesn't care where the pointer is pointing to.

But it's useful for you to check if the pointer is pointing to somewhere meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, to add to this long list of answers, the runtime will assign `0`, or `NULL` to the pointer. The memory at the other end, unless previously freed (`free()` or `operator delete`) if it was dynamically allocated (`malloc()` and `operator new`), or just cleaned up automatically because it was an `auto` (all locals by default).

Assigning `NULL` to a pointer that has valid memory at the other end creates a *memory leak*. A memory leak is when the OS thinks that a process is still using some memory, but the process has no handle on the memory (it has lost the address), and thus has no way of freeing it or using it. The memory will be cleaned up when the process terminates, but for long-running processes, or process that leak multiple times, or, worst of all, programs that leak large amounts of memory can cause big problems.

If a process leaks enough memory, at the least it will make the system sluggish and force the user to kill it, in worse circumstances, it would invoke the OOM killer (on systems with one), or worse, crash the entire system because of lack of memory. Also, if you dereference a `NULL` pointer, on any modern OS you will cause a segfault or bus error, and on ancient OS', you could destroy the system (eg. DOS).

Debuggers may notify you if they have enough information, you can also use static analysis tools to find memory leaks, or runtime tools like valgrind. Memory leaks are one of the biggest problems for C/C++ programs, and are something to look for carefully before realeasing code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a pointer to 0 does not solve a dangling pointer problem.  If the code thinks that a dangling pointer (by definition invalid) is valid, setting to 0 and dereferencing will still cause the program to manifest illegal behavior.

If the code happens to check a pointer for null before dereferencing, then setting the pointer to 0 can avoid illegal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer is more important than just convention. You are allowed to free a nullptr and have it not do anything. It is also used as convention that the pointer isn't pointing to anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why is assigning 0 to a pointer a solution to a dangling pointer?
```

@[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Dangling_pointer_detection)::

```
To expose dangling pointer errors, one common programming technique is to set
pointers to the null pointer or to an invalid address once the storage they 
point to has been released. When the null pointer is dereferenced 
(in most languages) the program will immediately terminate—there is no potential
for data corruption or unpredictable behavior. This makes the underlying 
programming mistake easier to find and resolve.  
This technique does not help when there are multiple copies of the pointer.
```

.

```
What does the OS/Debugger do when a pointer is assigned 0?
```

@[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_pointer)::

```
though, that the physical address zero is often directly accessible by hardware (for 
instance, it is directly accessible in x86 real mode, and it is where the interrupt  
table is stored), but modern operating systems usually map virtual address spaces in 
such a way that accessing address zero is forbidden.
```